# Android HttpURLConnection, non blocking read

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, nonblocking

I am implementing non-blocking downloading using HttpURLConnection, and here is my test code.
According to document using BufferdReader.ready() can tell me when to call read() without blocking.

However, I also found that, when all the data is read, BufferdReader.ready() is returning false. As a result, I can't distinguish "End of File" and "Not ready" from ready() call.

I can think of parsing "content-length" header from the response to guess file length, but as we know, content-length is not reliable.

Can any one tell me what could be a solution for this? 
In short, how can I find out if we hit "End of File" without calling read()?

```
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

char data[] = new char[100 * 1024];
int readLen = 0;
int offset = 0;
while(m_abort != true)
{
    if (in.ready())
    {
       readLen = in.read(data, offset, 256);
       if (readLen == -1)
         break;

       offset += readLen;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really don't want to sound rhetorical, but you're handling the `HttpURLConnection` on a background thread; why are you worried about  blocking reads?  If you have to cancel during a read, you can interrupt the thread...

Comment: Hi Kris, thank you for the input. I was basically implementing the whole thing in C code using JNI wrappers. (where thread interrupt does not exist) I probably need to have a new java class which has thread implementation in it that talks to JNI code. (so that i can get benefit of thread interrupt of Java). Thanks!

Comment: @krislarson (Http/s)URLConnection uses blocking, non-interruptible IO. That means it ignores thread interruption. Neither of connection.connect(), connection.getInputStream(), nor inputStream.read() react to thread interruptions.